# Derive from a object

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm wondering if its possible to inherit from a instanced object instead of a class. If so, where did I go wrong?

I have this simple code.

```
class Fruit:
    def printFruit(self):
         printFruit("Fruit Class")

myFruitObj = Fruit()

class Apple(myFruitObj):
    def printApple("Apple Class")

myApple = Apple()

myApple.printFruit()
myApple.printApple()
```

**Apple** is inheriting from **myFruitObj** .
I get the error:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters

if I add the `__init__` constructor, I get this:

> `__init__()` takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given.

Comment: You can't inherit from an instance...

Comment: You can't do that. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: One question; why? This makes no sense!

Comment: You *could* inherit from `myFruitObj.__class__`, though.

Comment: ... or `type(myFruitObj)`

Comment: Maybe you want to share the _attributes_ of the instance in the `Apple` class. If that is case, `self.__dict__.update(myFruitObj.__dict__)` would work.

Comment: so it is possible using myFruit.__class__. Thanks Chepner.

Comment: as for the why...I'm scripting for a vfx software, Nuke. In nuke there is a PAUSE button that stops the viewer from updating. The developers of Nuke added python access to all the other functions except the PAUSE button. I got the OBJECT using some pyqt children() searches, and now I need to add my custom functions to this OBJECT. I have found other pyqt methods that can help (QMetaObject), thought I'd ask if this were possible just to have in my back pocket.

Comment: @にか note that "The developers of Nuke [created API] access to all other functions except `xyz`" usually means "Don't mess with `xyz`, it's magic." The precise nature of that magic may be "This has a sloppy implementation and we can't guarantee it won't crash your computer if you mess with it" or it may be "The only way we could implement this feature is to circumvent security features of the language. Messing with this could corrupt your filesystem." Tread lightly where no maps dare lead ye, fair programmer.

Comment: @にか even in the most benign case: "We don't guarantee this functionality will remain backward compatible," even a minor version patch might break your plugin. Remember the face of your father and be true (to public/private API design.)

Comment: @Adam Thanks..I've already thought of reasons why they missed it, and I also put in a ticket to the developers. They are going to fix it in the new version, but for now it will be okay. At 10K a license, I doubt my employers will go to the new version any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from a class instance. This isn't possible. An object and a class are two different things.

An object is created when `Python` calls the `__new__()` method of a class. A new instance of that specific object is returned by `__new__()`. The instance is then initialized by the `__init__()` method. Mutliple instances of the *same* class can be created.

A class however, is only created once during import time. Python evaluates the `class` statement, and creates a new *class* object. When one class object inherits from another class object, the child class receives all of the attributes and method objects of the parent class.

Think of it this way: The class is the blueprint, and the object is *thing* *created* by the blueprint. When you create that thing, your design will follow the specifications of the blueprint.

Now say you wanted to modify the layout of the original blueprint in some way, but you still wanted to keep the old blueprint. Would you base your new blueprints based off of something *created* by the original blueprints?  No, of course not. You would based your design off of the blueprints themselves, not what was created by them.

The same  goes for classes. When you create a new object of a class, the basic structure of the object is created by the class - the blueprint. However, just like with the example above, when you want to inherit something from a class, you wouldn't try to inherit from an object *created* by the class. *Why*? Because you want to inherit the general structure of the class - the blueprints - not the specific structure and specific attributes of one of the classes *instances*.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFruitObj.__class__
```

This does the job.

```
class Fruit:
    def printFruit(self):
         printFruit("Fruit Class")

myFruitObj = Fruit()

class Apple(myFruitObj.__class__):
    def printApple("Apple Class")

myApple = Apple()

myApple.printFruit()
myApple.printApple()
```